# How to model voltage sources, current sources in graph and solve for voltages, currents?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, voltage-source, graph

I want to model the circuit as graph with vertices and edges and then solve for the voltages at every nodes and currents in any edge using graph method.
However, I got some confusion as in materials such as Network Analysis Synthesis by SK Pande and many others a voltage source is represent by a short and current source is open.
If so then how would you solve for the voltages and currents in vertices and edges?

(I know how to solve it normally but I want to do it with graph method for now)

[image]

This is the graph with the voltage source shorted and current source opened (removed from the graph).

I want to solve it using incident and conductance matrice.

[image]

[This](https://www.eeeguide.com/incidence-matrix/) is an example of solving current using incident matrix. However, they just present a graph not model from circuit to graph.

Comment: You need to show some attempt at a solution for homework type questions. Then, someone might be able to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: @Andyaka added, not much though as I don't know exactly how to model these sources to graph so I can solve it as in the example in the link.

Comment: @hana First off, incident matrices are found "everywhere." (Though they aren't always given the same name. Depends on discipline.) Not just in electronics. They are used in laying out directed acyclic graphs (DAGs) used in compiler technology, for example, or tree structures in general software, and many other places. And your link makes it pretty easy to understand. It was fine to read, I think. You do get to pick the direction you want for each edge. It's your call. Does that make it any easier? Or is it still mysterious? Also you are allowed to have two edges between the same node.

Comment: @periblepsis I think you misunderstood my question. Incident matrices are esay to get once you get the graph representation of the circuit. 
The problem I'm facing is how to model voltage sources, current sources to graph.
The link I posted does show a general way to solve for currents using incident matrix and it is easy to understand. 
However, as I also mentioned in the post, the link did that for a given graph not any electrical circuits.
I checked many sources to model from electrical circuits to graph but they seem to model circuits with resistors only  which is useless to me.

Comment: @hana You didn't write that much, so it's easy to meander. Now, from what you write, the "column space" of your question has gained another dimension. Are you saying that you don't have any problems at all ***except*** how to handle voltage and current sources as "edges" in the graph? That's it? That's your *only* issue?

Comment: @hana Go [here](https://www.youtube.com/@DarrenCrowdy/videos) and watch videos 1 to 15. At the end you should be able to ask a narrower question here, I think.

Comment: @periblepsis I belived so. I think videos #9 and #10 are what I'm looking for. Anways, I'll study that and get back after I finish that.

Comment: @hana Great. I think his "style" is a little off-putting to me. His 'acting' about using his imagination, I guess. (That said, people really should try and allow themselves the time to wonder about what things mean. So he's on-point about that!) He knows what he's doing. And, I think, some other folks here would benefit from the training he offers. Glad to hear that it may be helping.

Comment: @periblepsis the videos are good, his writing is a bit hard to read though. I had to watch videos several times to get it.

Comment: @hana The writing wasn't so bad for me because I knew what he was to write before he did. And he goes over the same thing several times. That said, it does take several go-throughs to pick up all the details well. There's a lot of meat in there that spreads out into other fields, almost instantly. For example, I see immediate uses in certain phases of compiler technology. If you find the videos worth your trouble, you should write Darren at Imperial and let him know. I barely know him through writing before. But I think he'd very much embrace a note from anyone.